# Swift protocol conformance by extension between frameworks

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, protocols

For various reasons I'm splitting the codebase for a Swift iOS app into a series of modules, mostly dependent in a fairly linear fashion.  The basis of this question is: **If I have a class in one module, and then extend it to conform to a protocol in another module, will all objects of that type conform automatically?**.  Let's call them *Module 1* & *Module 2* for now.

A consequence of this modularisation that not every cell for a given UITableView class will be declared within that same module. so to allow me to use cells from outwith that module I've declared a series of protocols describing the basic functions of a cell.  For example:

In *module 1*:

```
public protocol ActionableCell {
    func performAction()
}
```

Which is used by the tableview so every time a cell is selected, if it conforms to `ActionableCell` then `performAction()` is called on it.  This allows the tableview to handle taps on cells it does not know about.

So, in the tableview's class (*Module 1*):

```
open class SomeTableView: UITableView {
    // Blah

        open override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    // If the cell is actionable, inform it that it has been selected
    if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? ActionableCell {
        cell.performAction()
    }
}
```

However, sometimes the cell is declared in *Module 1*, but the action is not possible without some module further down the chain, so in *Module 1* I declare the class:

```
open class SomeCell: UITableViewCell {
}
```

Then in *module 2* I make that cell conform to `ActionableCell`.

```
extension SomeCell: ActionableCell {
    func performAction() {
        // Do Stuff
    }
}
```

So, just to clarify:

**In the first module:** `ActionableCell` is declared, `SomeTableView` is declared, `SomeCell` is declared but does **not** conform to `ActionableCell`.

**Then in the second module:** `SomeCell` is extended to conform to `ActionableCell`

If both modules are included & built in my project, but *Module 2* is not directly imported in the Swift file either in the tableview class (where the cast to `ActionableCell` is performed), or where the cell is created, will the cell conform to `ActionableCell` anyway, because the extension is part of the project?  If not, at what point is it important to import the extension?

I know that accessing the extended properties of `SomeCell` is not possible without importing the second module, but this is about whether it can be cast without importing the extension.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've realised this didn't receive any answers, and I've been using this method for a while now, so I thought I should post an answer.

It turns out class extensions are global - if one module extends a class, it is extended for every module by the virtue of that module being present.  This is independent of whether the second module is imported, only on it being installed.

So, e.g. if *Module A* contains class `Foo`, and *Module B* extends `Foo` to conform to some protocol (e.g. `Hashable`).  If *Module A* then checks for `Hashable` conformance, it will find that `Foo` does indeed conform if and only if *Module B* is also present.

Comment: What happens if both Module B and Module C extend `Foo` to conform to the same protocol? Which method implementations will be called by Module A?